# Get foreach items to show in a grid c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gridview, foreach

I am using [Weather WebService](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityForecastByZIP) and I have a gridview with the id `forecast`. How could I display foreach items in the gridview? I have tried using

```
forecast += item.Date.ToShortDateString() + "   " + item.Desciption + "|";
```

But I get the error

> *'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'forecast' and no extension method 'forecast' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*)

```
WeatherService.WeatherSoapClient weather = new WeatherService.WeatherSoapClient("WeatherSoap");
WeatherService.ForecastReturn for = weather.GetCityForecastByZIP(Zip.Text);

        if (for.Success)
        {
            response.Text = for.ResponseText;
            city.Text = for.City;
            State.Text = for.State;
            WeatherStationCity.Text = for.WeatherStationCity;

            foreach (var item in for.ForecastResult)
            {
                  forecast += item.Date.ToShortDateString() + "   " + item.Desciption + "|";
            }
```

Comment: I think as per your error you haven't posted correct code! and what is `forecast` here?

Comment: i have posted the right code, the gridview id is forecast. im not sure of how to get the forecast results to display in a gridview for the week :/ @yogi970

Comment: Make a `datatable` with the service OP and bind your gridview with this `datatable`

Comment: where is forecast defined?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true` or not set at all(by default it is true) then no need to loop through your data and bind the gridview. If you want to show the `Date` & `Description` as separate columns then you can use a markup like this:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="forecast" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Desciption " DataField="Desciption " />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

This will display your data without formatting, but if you want some formatting to be done then either do it before assigning the datasource (by storing it in a DataTable or Custom List) or in the `RowDataBound` event of gridview.

Comment: @whateggs - Then create a custom type as I explained later, fill it and then assign to your gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code. `ForecastItem` class should be defined in a separate file. And add two columns to your gridview, setting `DataField` property of them to `Date` and `Description` (or set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true)

```
public class ForecastItem
{
  public string Date {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}

.
.
.

WeatherService.WeatherSoapClient weather = new WeatherService.WeatherSoapClient("WeatherSoap");
WeatherService.ForecastReturn for = weather.GetCityForecastByZIP(Zip.Text);

if (for.Success)
{
    response.Text = for.ResponseText;
    city.Text = for.City;
    State.Text = for.State;
    WeatherStationCity.Text = for.WeatherStationCity;
    List<ForecastItem> forecastItems = new List<ForecastItem>();
    foreach (var item in for.ForecastResult)
    {
         forecastItems.Add(new ForcastItem() {
             Date = item.Date.ToShortDateString(),
             Description = item.Desciption
         });
    }
    forecast.DataSource = forecastItems;
    forecast.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to drag-drop the XML output from the service into VS 2013 and it will create the class definitions for you.

Comment: @MikeWeber, I didn't know that. Please elaborate. Drag what and drop where?!

Comment: sorry, that was partially incorrect - if you copy the XML output and Edit->Paste Special -> XML in VS, it will generate the classes for you.  Not quite drag and drop.